# snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: Failed to get the response

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble establishing a connection from snowflake to python (using the python snowflake.connector).

I get a message saying -
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://my_company.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=a3d18cc0-14b8-4ed0-aeaf-054b0b138c3d&databaseName=DEPARTMENT_SALES&schemaName=SALES_MONTHLY&warehouse=INVENTORY_SALES&request_guid=58070c2e-faf7-418b-8bf1-aa22e3dc537b

Below is the code. I ran this code on window (locally on my laptop). Can anyone offer some helps? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='firstname_lastname',
    password='xxxxx',
    #account='my_company',
    account='my_company.us-east-1',
    warehouse = 'INVENTORY_SALES',
    database='DEPARTMENT_SALES',
    schema='SALES_MONTHLY' )
```

Comment: Does the account name have an "underscore" in it? If yes, can you try instead with hyphen? As in like this :account='my-company.us-east-1

Comment: Thank Srinath, I tried 'my-company.us-east-1' but I still get the same error. Beside, I ran select current_account() in snowflake and it shows my_company (with underscore)

Comment: Are you able to login via Snowflake UI using same URL ?

Comment: able to log in with the 1st part of the URL which is  https://my_company.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: Are you able to generate the Python [log](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#python) and provide the output (masked)?

Answer (score 1):

For 'account' I actually had to use the value '<org>-<account>' in configuration. This paged proved useful:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html

In short, there are two values I needed: 'org' and 'account'. There is a 'locator' identifier that is deprecated but still visible in the UI at the time of this writing.

As for `snowsql` CLI, I had to do the same, but in addition set region to 'us-west-2' (even though my Snowflake instance is in 'us-east-2'!) to satisfy SSL certificate checks. The CLI then successfully connected using the correct domain of '<account>.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com'.

Snowsql version: 1.2.23

Comment: You appear to have posted multiple identical answers recently. If the questions are the same, you should flag them as duplicates. If they're different, then you should tailor your answers to each question. Identical answers are liable to be deleted.

Comment: I can't leave comments but wanted to get this info on this thread. It's good info for both places I posted. Guess I'll pick one and delete my post from the other.

Comment: Thanks Ormu5 for your advice. I posted this question around 9 months ago and found out it turns out to be company’s fire wall issue. It just doesn’t let me retrieve data from snowflakes programmatically